# How to set a custom attribute on a view programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to set a custom attribute to my view programmatically, to set a validation state.

First, I created this layout for a text field:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/state_color" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- main color -->
<item
    android:bottom="1.5dp"
    android:left="2.5dp"
    android:right="2.5dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
<item android:bottom="5.0dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Then defined this attribute:

```
<attr name="validation_state" format="enum">
        <enum name="None" value="0"/>
        <enum name="Error" value="1"/>
        <enum name="Warning" value="2"/>
        <enum name="Success" value="3"/>
</attr>
```

I also defined these color definitions state_color.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:color="@color/state_error"
    app:validation_state="Error"/>

<item
    android:color="@color/state_warning"
    app:validation_state="Warning"/>

<item
    android:color="@color/state_success"
    app:validation_state="Success"/>

<item
    android:color="@color/state_default"/>
```

And last I created an own EditText class which extends the one of the Android framework

```
    private static final int[] STATE_MANDATORY = { R.attr.mandatory };
private static final int[] STATE_READONLY = { R.attr.readonly };
private static final int[] STATE_VALIDATION_STATE = { R.attr.validation_state };

private boolean _mandatory = false;
private boolean _readonly = false;
private ValidationState _validationState = ValidationState.NONE;

public mcEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setMandatory(final boolean mandatory)
{
    _mandatory = mandatory;
    refreshDrawableState();
}

@Override
public void setReadOnly(final boolean readonly)
{
    _readonly = readonly;
    refreshDrawableState();
}

@Override
public void setValidationState(final ValidationState state)
{
    _validationState = state;
    refreshDrawableState();
}

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace)
{
    final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 3);
    if (_mandatory)
    {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_MANDATORY);
    }
    if (_readonly)
    {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_READONLY);
    }
    if (_validationState != ValidationState.NONE)
    {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_VALIDATION_STATE);
    }
    return drawableState;

}
```

I've added this color definition to my view and it also recognises it, so the error state gets shown. But now I don't know how to switch between the different states. I need to set programmatically the attribute "validation_state", but how is that possible?

Comment: see the 'Apply Custom Attributes' in the Android Doc : https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: @ThomasMary: This part only describes how to read the attributes, not how I can change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that android does not support enum attributes for this kind of work. You must have to work with boolean attributes

```
<attr name="validation_state_none" format="boolean"/>
<attr name="validation_state_error" format="boolean"/>
...
```

The most common example of what you trying to do is like focusable, editable attributes. And it's handled with atomic booleans attributes in [android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/StateSet.java)

Another solution that might help you (Not tested) is to create your own drawable programmatically. Take a look at [DrawableContainer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/DrawableContainer.html) and [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

Comment: Ok thanks for this. I hoped it's possible with enum, but then I'll do it like this :)